# How to create dynamic Map key in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, collections, dictionary

I have tried to create a map like example below...

```
var myMap= {"one": 1,"two": "two","three": 3.0};
```

So, I iterate them like:

```
for (var key in myMap) {

window.alert("myMapmap property \"" + key + "\" = " + myMap[key]);

}
```

If my data is **dynamic**... and I want to add each of them in to map... how the codes should be like? And I expect the key is not static...I mean the data taken from other source like database, that wasn't define before..

Thanks before

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
var dataSource = ...;
while (var o = dataSource.get()) {
     myMap[o.key] = o.value;
}

for (var key in myMap) {
     alert("key : " + key + " value : " + myMap[key]);
}
```

You can simply write to an object using array like syntax.

How and where you get your data is upto you.

Comment: @Stephen `myMap = {}` reset it to an empty map.

Comment: how can you remove a specific element?

Comment: tf is dataSource.get? Non-ECMA.

Comment: how do I check if myMap has keys or is empty?

Comment: @dierre `var isEmpty = Object.keys(myMap).length === 0`

Comment: Tnx, although I'm thinking cycling keys could give me more compatibility.

Answer (score 8):

Dynamic **values** and **keys** can be added using this notation:

```
var myMap = {}; // Create empty map
myMap["some" + "dynamic" + "key"] = "some" + "dynamic" + "variable";
```